# Require cycle: node_modules/jsan/lib/index.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/cycle.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/utils.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/index.js

Tags: react-native

Getting the waring in the console any solution:

```
WARN: Require cycle: node_modules/jsan/lib/index.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/cycle.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/utils.js -> node_modules/jsan/lib/index.js
```